# ExpandableListView child looses onChildClick listener when adding views to layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview

This is my first post so please be gentle, I will try to explain in the best way I can.

I have an `ExpandableListView`, with a number of children. When I press one of these children, I want to add an extra  `LinearLayout` (which I have already defined in a xml file) to their original layout.

I have managed to do this successfully, however, after the child is updated, it no longer triggers the **`onChildClick event`**.

As i have said, this is my first post, i will edit in any details if requested.

Comment: If you post some code or what have u tried people gonna help you more

Comment: yeah post some code... specifically, I want to know if the child you add is like the rest, or if on the contrary it includes clickable elements (clickable childs disable parent onchildclick). If the case is the latter, you need to assign an onclicklistener tothe children itself rather than to the parent.